# Rollup Summary fields are not updated

Tags: lightning-aura-components, roll-up-summary, lightning-data-service

We have built a custom lightning page showing account summary in the top and users can create income and expense (custom object) as child records to account. We have rollup summary fields on account object to show total income and expense.

Rollup Summary fields are updated immediately in lighting data service  component (without any explicit refresh) and displayed in the summary section when new income or expense record is created or when the amount is updated for the existing record. But the rollup summary fields are not updated when income or expense record is deleted. To investigate this behaviour we added a refresh button on the account summary component to explicitly refresh the data service component. Even this explicit refresh is only working after sometime (around 30 sec) to reflect the deletion on the rollup summary field.